# I'm not receiving an error, but I can't seem to get UDF's working in xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

I recently installed xlwings addin and used the **xlwings** quickstart test method to create **test.xlsm** and **test.py** files. I checked the *test.py* file to verify a test function (hello) is in the file.

When I import functions I see a prompt saying

> xlwings server running, clsid={D064D11A-82DD-4F12-BC83-7E96AB444311}

When I type in the function =hello(a1) into Excel I get a **#NAME?** error.

Any idea what the problem could be? I've verified that the Interpreter: input box points to the python.exe file and the PYTHONPATH: input box lists the folder containing the *test.xlsm* and *test.py* files.

Comment: The #Name error is usually because the called function does not exist.  To check, press Alt-F11 to open the VBA Editor.  There should be a module called xlwings, with a function called hello.  If it is not there, the import process did not work; check the log file.  If it is, let us know.